# Continuous requestAnimationFrame in React

Tags: reactjs, animation

I'm working on some sort of 'continuous' animation. Say a `div` translates from its current location `200px` to the right. There's an option to change the distance of translation. While its animating, the user changes from `200px` to `400px`. The `div` should still move smoothly until it reaches its final point which is `400px` from its previous location. I have done the basic moving animation, however I can't figure out how to make it continues without jumping when the distance changes.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shannon-jcrdp) that I'm working on which best illustrates my point above and what I'm struggling with. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :))

**Edit:** Steps to reproduce the jumping problem:

- Open the sandbox
- Click the 'Toggle' button
- Click the 'Add distance' button
- While the red `div` animates, click 'Add distance' button again

And you should see the `div` jumping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a way to fix your code so that it works as you want, though I would suggest going in another direction. There are several animation libraries in React that can help you solve this problem. The resulting code is also going to be more portable.

For your specific need, I would suggest using a library called [`react-move`](https://github.com/react-tools/react-move). It is part of the [`react-tools`](https://github.com/react-tools) which provides other cool libraries. I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-microservice-z98go) with my take on your problem using `react-move`.

I only took the `transform` line for your code, since I wanted to focus on how you could integrate the library into your example.

To create the animation, I imported a component from `react-move` called [`Animate`](https://react-move.js.org/#/component-api/animate). It's the main component of the library. You use this component to wrap a `function` using the `function as child` pattern. This function will receive a `state` object with information regarding the animated element. It also consumes a `start`, `update`, `enter`, and `leave` function, that represents the `state` for those actions.

Inside you `function as child` function is where you define the animation. In our case, we want to translate the `Box` along its `x` axis, using the `x` value provided on the `state` object.

**OBS: On my example the `Box` returns to the start (`x === 0`) when its offset value is bigger than the window's width.**

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. Works perfectly. Thanks for your help